# Populating a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, random, dynamic

I am trying to populate a dynamically allocated 2D array.

Specifically, I am trying to input random numbers into an array.

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

int i, j, num_students = 10, num_grades = 4;
int **array;

srand(time(NULL));


array = malloc(sizeof(int *) * num_students);

for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_grades);

for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i)
{
    printf("Student %d has grades: ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j)
        array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
    free(array[i]);
}

free(array);

return 0;

}
```

The output:

```
Student 0 has grades: 0 
Student 1 has grades: 0 
Student 2 has grades: 0 
Student 3 has grades: 0 
Student 4 has grades: 0 
Student 5 has grades: 0 
Student 6 has grades: 0 
Student 7 has grades: 0 
Student 8 has grades: 0 
Student 9 has grades: 0
```

I do not know why it is printing 0 instead of the random numbers.

Comment: Note: Had code not defined `j` until the loop like `for (int j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j)`, then the compiler would have error-ed on `printf("%d ", array[i][j]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `{ ... }`...

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j)
        array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
```

Is the same as

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
}
printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
```

,but it should be

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind one of the glorious hills.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing brackets around the inner for loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j)
{
    array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
    printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation doesn't control your scope (as it does in Python, for example). Your for-loop only iterates over the first line:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j)
    array[i][j] = rand() % 101; // <- only this is iterated over
    printf("%d ", array[i][j]); // <- this only runs once, after the for-loop
```

Ensure that you've encapsulated both lines in braces:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j) {
    array[i][j] = rand() % 101;
    printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for picking up on the simple mistake.